# Aggregate MongoDB query within nested arrays over multiple documents

Tags: mongodb

I am doing a little hobby project for friends' disc golf results.

I'm fairly new to MongoDB and I've stuck on a query. What I want to do is to return a JSON object on the form `[{player: "Name", totalThrows: (sum of Totalt field), total+/-: (sum of +/- field)}]`.

So in short: I want to aggregate each players total throws (Total field) and total+/-, over 3 different documents in my database.

The final JSON would look like this: `[{player: "Tormod", totalThrows: 148, total+/-: 24}, {player: "Martin", totalThrows: 149, total+/-: 25}, {player: "Andreas", totalThrows: 158, total+/-: 34}]`

The picture below shows my document as it's saved in MongoDB. The results array consist of the results of a specific player discgolf results. There is also not a set order on which player is first in the results array in the different documents. Each document represents a new round (think of playing 3 different days).

[image]

Code:

```
aggregate(
        [
            {$unwind: "$results"},
            {$group: { 
                player: "$results.PlayerName",
                throws: "$results.Totalt"
            }},
            {$group: {
                _id: "$_id", 
                totalThrows: {$sum: "$results.Totalt"}
            }}
        ])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/aaKv3aaCeCi

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: So i've been trying alot of different stuff, most recently i've been onto something like this: 
 [
                {$unwind: "$results"},
                {$group: { 
                    player: "$results.PlayerName",
                    throws: "$results.Totalt"
                }},
                {$group: {
                    _id: "$_id", 
                    totalThrows: {$sum: "$results.Totalt"}
                }}
            ])

Comment: Can you add your code to the question and share a [MongoPlayground](http://mongoplayground.net) link with some sample data?

Comment: Done @ArunKumarMohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an `_id` field (the group by expression) to the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group) stage and use [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to sum the `Totalt` and `+/-` values. Since the values are strings, you should convert them to integers using [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt) before summing them. Finally, you can project the values based on the desired structure.

Btw, it looks like most of the numeric fields are stored as strings in the documents. I would recommend you update the documents converting them all to numbers and make sure only numbers are added to the numeric fields in the new documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$results",
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$results.PlayerName",
      totalThrows: {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$results.Totalt",
        },
      },
      "total+/-": {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$results.+/-",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      player: "$_id",
      totalThrows: "$totalThrows",
      "total+/-": "$total+/-",
    },
  },
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_xCn79kYpkt)

Comment: The god! I guess I was semi-close, thank you so much Arun!